# Asymptotics of product of harmonic numbers

Tags: asymptotics, products, harmonic-numbers

Consider the product

$$p_n = \prod_{k=1}^n H_k$$

of $n$ successive harmonic numbers $H_k=\sum_{i=1}^k 1/i$.

The sequence of the $p_n$ is listed in OEIS as [`A097423/A097424`](http://oeis.org/search?q=A097423).

I am looking for the asymptotic behaviour of $p_n$ as $n\to\infty$.

My first attemps are based on the asymptotic behaviour of the harmonic number itself

$$H_n \simeq \log(n) + \gamma +\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{12 n^2}+...$$

Defining

$$q_{a,1}(n) = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{H_k}{\log(k) + \gamma +\frac{1}{2k}}$$
$$q_{a,2}(n) = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{H_k}{\log(k) + \gamma +\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{12 k^2}}$$

I found numerically that

$$q_{a,1}(10^3)\simeq 0.903394162407764$$
$$q_{a,2}(10^3)\simeq 1.006552015286574$$

Questions

1) Are there closed expressions for the $q_{a,i}(\infty)$ in terms of known constants?

2) What can be said about the asymptotic behaviour of the products

$$r_{a,1}(n) = \prod_{k=1}^n \left( \log(k) + \gamma +\frac{1}{2k}\right)$$
$$r_{a,2}(n) = \prod_{k=1}^n \left(\log(k) + \gamma +\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{12 k^2}\right)$$

Comment: You are right, Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for migrating the question

Comment: I suppose typo's : the numerical values are for the $q$'s and, in the last equations, it should be $k$ instead of $n$.

Comment: Yes, a typo. Thanks. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious thing is to
extract the $\ln(n)$
from the product.

$\begin{array}\\
p_n 
&= \prod_{k=1}^n H_k\\
&= \prod_{k=1}^n \left( \log(k) + \gamma +f(1/k)\right)
\qquad\text{where }f(x) = x/2+O(x^2)\\
&= \prod_{k=2}^n  \log(k)\prod_{k=1}^n \left( 1 + (\gamma +f(1/k))/\log(k)\right)
\qquad\text{start the first product at 2 otherwise it is zero}\\
&=g(n)h(n)\\
\end{array}
$

Note:
This estimate changed.

$\begin{array}\\
g(n)
&=\prod_{k=2}^n  \log(k)\\
\text{so}\\
\log(g(n))
&=\sum_{k=2}^n  \log\log(k)\\
&\approx\int_{k=2}^n  \log\log(x)dx\\
&=  x\log\log(x)|_{2}^n-\int_2^n dx/\ln(x)\\
&\approx n\log\log(n)-n/\log(n)\\
\end{array}
$

and
$h(n)
=\prod_{k=1}^n \left( 1 + (\gamma +f(1/k))/\log(k)\right)
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(h(n))
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \log\left( 1 + (\gamma +f(1/k))/\log(k)\right)\\
&\approx\sum_{k=1}^n (\gamma +f(1/k))/\log(k))\\
&\approx\dfrac{n\gamma}{\log(n)}+O(\log\log(n))
\\
\end{array}
$

so,
finally,
$\log(p_n)
\approx n\log\log(n)-n/\log(n)+\dfrac{n\gamma}{\log(n)}+O(\log\log(n))
= n\log\log(n)-(1-\gamma)n/\log(n)+O(\log\log(n))
$.

This could be tested.
$\log(g(n))$
could have more terms from
a better estimate for
$\sum_{k=1}^n  \log\log(k)$.

Comment: Thanks for your analysis. From be quick and dirty calculations, it seems that $\log(p_n)
\approx n\log\log(n)-\dfrac{n\gamma}{\log(n)}$. Would you check ?

Comment: I more accurately estimated the sum and ended up with $-(1-\gamma)n/\log(n)$. That agrees better with yours.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer since based on numerical simulations.*

If $$p_n= \prod_{k=1}^n H_k$$ it seems that $\log(p_n)$ is almost linear with respect to $n$ (this has been done of $1 \leq n \leq 1000$.

Using data points from $100$ to $10000$ by steps of $10$, a quick and dirty nonlinear regression for $\log(p_n)=a+b \,n^c$ leads to
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & -16.152 & 0.284863 & \{-16.72,-15.59\} \\
 b & 1.08280   & 0.002889 & \{1.0770,1.0885\} \\
 c & 1.07928  & 0.000372 & \{1.07854,1.0800\} \\
\end{array}$$

For $n=1000$, the regression leads to $\log(p_{1000})=1856.25$ while the exact value is $\approx 1855.48$.

**Edit after marty cohen's answer**

Reusing  the same data set as before, we effectively find for the model
$$\log(p_n)=a n \log (\log (n))+\frac{b n}{\log (n)}+c$$ the following results
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 1.00819   & 0.00013 & \{1.00793,1.00845\} \\
 b & -0.653283 & 0.00185 & \{-0.656948,-0.649618\} \\
 c & 1.64706   & 0.02723 & \{1.59301,1.70112\} \\
\end{array}$$ corresponding to a sum of squares equal to $0.262703$.

Discarding the constant $c$ term, we should get 
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 1.00110   & 0.00035 & \{1.00041,1.00179\} \\
 b & -0.549559 & 0.00428 & \{-0.558049,-0.541069\} 
\end{array}$$ corresponding to a sum of squares equal to $10.2736$.

For both case, $|b|\approx \gamma$